# Json spark to redshift

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I have a file that has multiple nested jsons, I would like topush to redshift, i figured to start off with I can just save the entire row as one column string then save

I am new to both spark and scala so excuse the ignorance please, but it seems that reading the file as json will automatically infer a schema which I cant save to redshift because the connector im [using](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/tree/master/tutorial) cant save the schema for nested jsons

So my question is this, how can I read in a file that has a nested json, save each row completely in a table with one column "message"

If it helps here is a sample json that I want to break down, maybe to different tables?

Assuming I have a sample json as

```
{
    "OrderId": "foo",
    "LegacyOrderId": 123,
    "NotifiyCustomer": true,
    "OrderResolutionStatus": "OkByBox",
    "CustomerId": 123,
    "RestaurantId": 132111,
    "OrderContainer": {
        "Id": "foo",
        "LegacyId": 123,
        "ApplicationInfo": {
            "UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13F69 Safari/601.1",
            "ClientIp": "0.0.0.0",
            "JeFeature": "sadsad",
            "ApplicationName": "Resadasdsab",
            "ApplicationVersion": "1.0.10444.0"
        },
        "Order": {
            "foo": "Fasdsaasdsdse. ",
            "foo": "asdasdsads",
            "fooDate": "2016-07-06T10:58:40.3579409+00:00",
            "InitialDueDate": "2016-07-06T12:10:00+00:00",
            "InitialDueDateWithUtcOffset": "2016-07-06T13:10:00+01:00",
            "DueDate": "2016-07-06T12:10:00+00:00",
            "DueDateWithUtcOffset": "2016-07-06T13:10:00+01:00",
            "foo": true,
            "foo": true
        },
        "RestaurantInfo": {
            "Id": "34421159",
            "Name": "Casdadasdase",
            "PhoneNumber": "0fdsfddsf2",
            "AddressLines": ["5asdasddasad"],
            "City": "London",
            "Postcode": "SE1 3BR",
            "Longitude": 0.012155,
            "Latitude": 51.920357,
            "DispatchMethod": "JctV3",
            "SeoName": "caadssadasdas6",
            "TempOffline": false,
            "Offline": false
        },
        "PaymentInfo": {
            "OrderId": "foo",
            "PaymentLines": [{
                "Type": "Cash",
                "Value": 18.8,
                "CardFee": 0.0
            }],
            "DriverTipValue": 0.0,
            "Total": 18.8,
            "TotalComplementary": 0.0,
            "PaidDate": "2016-07-06T10:58:51.7863535+00:00"
        },
        "CustomerInfo": {
            "Id": "7604asdsa879",
            "Email": "oasdasd@rest.com",
            "Name": "Lysadsadasi",
            "Address": "3sadsadsadsdsaasde",
            "City": "London",
            "Postcode": "E11 3sG",
            "PhoneNumber": "asdsads",
            "TimeZone": "GMT Standard Time",
            "PreviousJeOrderCount": 22,
            "PreviousRestuarantOrderCount": 0
        },
        "BasketInfo": {
            "BasketId": "asdsdas",
            "MenuId": 119949,
            "Items": [{
                "ProductId": 1392310,
                "ProductTypeId": 366,
                "MenuCardNumber": "96",
                "Name": "Casdasdsaef",
                "Description": "In batter<br />\r\n<strong>Spicy</strong>",
                "Synonym": "",
                "UnitPrice": 52.5,
                "CombinedPrice": 52.5,
                "MealParts": [],
                "OptionalAccessories": [],
                "RequiredAccessories": [],
                "Discounts": [],
                "MultiBuyDiscounts": []
            }, {
                "ProductId": 12233,
                "ProductTypeId": 44218,
                "MenuCardNumber": "418",
                "Name": "Aasdsaddsadsadsadsa",
                "Description": "",
                "Synonym": "",
                "UnitPrice": 7.5,
                "CombinedPrice": 7.5,
                "MealParts": [],
                "OptionalAccessories": [],
                "RequiredAccessories": [],
                "Discounts": [],
                "MultiBuyDiscounts": []
            }, {
                "ProductId": 13917482,
                "ProductTypeId": 365,
                "MenuCardNumber": "129",
                "Name": "Szasdsadsaadssad",
                "Description": "asdsaddsadssaddas",
                "Synonym": "",
                "UnitPrice": 5.8,
                "CombinedPrice": 5.8,
                "MealParts": [],
                "OptionalAccessories": [],
                "RequiredAccessories": [],
                "Discounts": [],
                "MultiBuyDiscounts": []
            }],
            "Discounts": [],
            "SubTotal": 18.8,
            "ToSpend": 0.0,
            "MultiBuyDiscount": 0.0,
            "Discount": 0.0,
            "DeliveryCharge": 0.0,
            "Total": 18.8
        },
        "IsLocked": true
    },
    "Id": "c35d48c1-268f-4e46-81d9-700afc22f2d9",
    "TimeStamp": "2016-07-06T10:59:22.982145Z",
    "RaisingComponent": "Leasdsadasdasw",
    "Tenant": "uk"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that Redshift requires the JSON structure to be isomorphic to the top level keys in the JSON source. There are a number of other limitations, e.g., can't load nested arrays, can't load more than 2MB per file, etc.

My suggestion (and the solution I have *just* implemented personally) is:

- Load the data into a Spark dataframe `sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")`
- Let Spark infer the schema if needed `.option("inferSchema", "true")`
- Manipulate it as a sequence of dataframes `val nextDf = df.[filter|explode|select|…etc]`
- Write the final *flat* dataframe(s) to Redshift `finalDf.write.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift").option(…`

Comment: thanks for this, Im really new to scala so not sure of the syntax to do this. So please excuse the ignorance. Ive attached a sample nested json to the question. Can you help me out with the syntax?

Comment: You really only need a minimal amount of Scala knowledge. I'd suggest using `spark-shell` a lot and just trying things out. Go through the `spark-redshift` tutorial here https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/tree/master/tutorial

Comment: From the looks of you JSON you're going to want to create multiple tables in Redshift. To get the "rows" from the nested JSON arrays, e.g., `OrderContainer.BasketInfo.Items[]`, you either use `.explode()` in Scala or `LATERAL VIEW explode()` inside a `.sql()` call.

Comment: perfect ill have a look. Thanks mate!